# How to get the contract address after deploying contract without using truffle?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, nodejs

I'm currently using web3 0.20.6 and I'm planning to stay in web3@0.20.6 because there are issues with HTTP in the beta versions of web3@1.0.0-beta.* like

> The current provider doesn't support subscriptions: HttpProvider

Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the contract address after being deployed.
Because in web3@1.0.0-beta.*, we can use like the example below to get the contract address.

```
    contract.deploy({
        data: '0x'+bin,
        arguments: [request.body.vin, cost, request.body.buyer]
    })
    .send({
        from: request.body.dealer,
        gas: gas
    })
    .on('receipt', receipt => {
        util.log(`>>>>> contractApi - Contract sucessfully deployed @ address: ${receipt.contractAddress}`);

        data.contract_address = receipt.contractAddress;

        response.json(data);
    });
```

But how do you do it in web3@0.20.6 ? I couldn't find the solutions online without using truffle. I'm not planning to use truffle as well.

What I did try was,

```
const deployedContract = LoginContract.new ({
    data: '0x'+binLogin,
    from: '6ded1c5b448819a6cde4293e33fbe54583ef5c52',
    gas: 4700000
});

contractData = deployedContract.address;
util.log(`>>>>> setup - Login Contract sucessfully deployed @ address: ${contractData}`)
```

But the result in console is undefined address

> 22 Mar 14:04:15 - >>>>> setup - Login Contract sucessfully deployed @ address: undefined

Then after about 5-10 seconds, this popped up in the console

> Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.

I'm like super confused right now because the gas amount should be sufficient.

**EDIT 1**
Thanks to @mirg's answer, the deployment is successful. However, I noticed that the instructions below the contract deployment:

```
contractData = deployedContract.address;
util.log(`>>>>> setup - Login Contract sucessfully deployed @ address: ${contractData}`)
```

continue to run and does not wait for the contract deployment to complete/finish.

How do you make further instructions to wait and process the result of that contract deployment?
In web3@1.0.0-beta.* it is achievable by using

```
.on('receipt', receipt => {}
```

But I have no idea how it is achieved using web3@0.20.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case you're not passing the constructor parameters to the deploy function.

```
const deployedContract = LoginContract.new (request.body.vin, cost, request.body.buyer, {
    data: '0x'+binLogin,
    from: '6ded1c5b448819a6cde4293e33fbe54583ef5c52',
    gas: 4700000
}, function(err, myContract){
    if(!err) {
       // NOTE: The callback will fire twice!
       // Once the contract has the transactionHash property set and once its deployed on an address.

       // e.g. check tx hash on the first call (transaction send)
       if(!myContract.address) {
           console.log(myContract.transactionHash) // The hash of the transaction, which deploys the contract

       // check address on the second call (contract deployed)
       } else {
           console.log(myContract.address) // the contract address
       }

       // Note that the returned "myContractReturned" === "myContract",
       // so the returned "myContractReturned" object will also get the address set.
    }
  }));
```

this should work [ref](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#returns-49)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mirg, I noticed that the instructions after the contract deployment continue to run without waiting for the deployment to finish. How to make the instructions to wait in web3@0.20.6 just like in web3@1.0.0-beta.*?

Comment: you have to provide a callback (which will be fired twice). See my updated answer